# Python - how to send file from filesystem with a unicode filename?

Tags: python, unicode, flask

So I am using Flask to serve some files. I recently downgraded the project from Python 3 to Python 2.7 so it would work with more extensions, and ran into a problem I did not have before. I am trying to serve a file from the filesystem with a Japanese filename, and when I try `return send_from_directory(new_folder_path, filename, as_attachment=True)`
I get `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 15-20: ordinal not in range(128)`. in `quote_header_value = str(value)` (that is a werkzeug thing).
I have template set to display the filename on the page by just having {{filename}} in the HTML and it is displaying just fine, so I'm assuming it is somehow reading the name from the filesystem? Only when I try send_from_directory so the user can download it does it throw this error. I tried a bunch of combinations of `.encode('utf-8') and`.decode('utf-8')`none of which worked at all and I'm getting very frustrated with this. In Python 3 everything just worked seamlessly because everything was treated as unicode, and searching for a way to solve this brought up results that it seems I would need a degree in compsci to wrap my head around. Does anyone have a fix for this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after wrestling with it under the hood for a while I fixed it, but not in a very elegant way, I had to modify the source of some werkzeug things. In "http.py", I replaced `str(value)` with `unicode(value)`, and replaced every instance of "latin-1" with "utf-8" in both http.py and datastructures.py. It fixed the problem, file gets downloaded fine in both the latest Firefox and Chrome. As I said before, I would rather not have to modify the source of the libraries I am using because this is a pain when deploying/testing on different systems, so if anyone has a better fix for this please share. I've seen some people recommend just making the filename part of the URL but I cannot do this as I need to keep my URLs simple and clean.

Comment: You could have used `return send_from_directory(new_folder_path, unicode(filename), as_attachment=True)`.

It would have spared you the library tinkering.