# Flask UnicodeDecodeError error occured

Tags: python, unicode, flask, decode

Excel file contain korean text.
i don't find solution..
help me!

this is flask code

```
@app.route('/usecase/excel', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_excel():
    file_name = "usecase.xls"
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, file_name)
```

error occured..

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: What function raises the `UnicodeDecodeError`? Can you paste the full traceback? What request triggers the failure? You need to give us the input request.

Comment: Maybe this question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715132/python-how-to-send-file-from-filesystem-with-a-unicode-filename

Comment: unicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Answer (score 0):

As recommended here,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17681884/5417164

if you want to use in production, you do not want to use flask to serve static files.